# Full derivation of impulse formula for collision response

Tags: physics, simulation, collision-detection, derivation-of-formulae

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response#Impulse-Based_Reaction_Model) page says that the equation for impulse-based collision response is:

\begin{equation}
 j_r = \frac{ -(1 + e) v_r \cdot n }
{
{m_1}^{-1} + {m_2}^{-1}
+ ({I_1}^{-1}(r_1 \times n) \times r_1
 + {I_2}^{-1}(r_2 \times n) \times r_2
  ) \cdot n}\end{equation}

What is the full working out for this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive the equation:

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
 j_r = \frac{ -(1 + e) v_r \cdot n }
{
{m_1}^{-1} + {m_2}^{-1}
+ ({I_1}^{-1}(r_1 \times n) \times r_1
 + {I_2}^{-1}(r_2 \times n) \times r_2
  ) \cdot n}\end{equation}

we know that for linear velocity,
\begin{equation}\tag{2a} v_1' = v_1 - \frac{j_r}{m_1} n  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{2b} v_2' = v_2 + \frac{j_r}{m_2} n  \end{equation}

and for angular velocity,
\begin{equation}\tag{3a} {\omega}_1' = {\omega}_1 - \frac{j_r}{I_1} {r_1 \times n} \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{3b} {\omega}_2' = {\omega}_2 + \frac{j_r}{I_2} {r_2 \times n} \end{equation}

at the contact point, inital velocity is,
\begin{equation}\tag{4a} v_{pi} = v_i + {\omega}_i \times r_i   \end{equation}

and final velocity is,
\begin{equation}\tag{4b} v_{pi}' = v_i' + {\omega}_i' \times r_i   \end{equation}
similarly for relative velocity,
\begin{equation}\tag{5a} v_r = v_{p2} -  v_{p1}  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{5b} v_r' = v_{p2}' -  v_{p1}'  \end{equation}

Newton's law of restitution,
\begin{equation}\tag{6a} v_r' \cdot n = -e v_r \cdot n \end{equation}

substitute (5b) into (6a),
\begin{equation}\tag{6b} (v_{p2}' -  v_{p1}') \cdot n = -e v_r \cdot n   \end{equation}

substitute (4b) into (6b),

\begin{equation}\tag{6c} \Big((v_2' + {\omega}_2' \times r_2) - (v_1' + {\omega}_1' \times r_1)\Big) \cdot n = -e v_r \cdot n  \end{equation}

substitute (2a) and (2b) into (6c),

\begin{equation}\tag{6d} \bigg(\Big((v_2 + \frac{j_r}{m_2} n) + {\omega}_2' \times r_2) - ((v_1 - \frac{j_r}{m_1} n) + {\omega}_1' \times r_1\Big)\bigg) \cdot n = -e v_r \cdot n  \end{equation}

expanding and simplifying left side,

\begin{equation}\tag{7a} LHS =  (v_2 + \frac{j_r}{m_2} n + {\omega}_2' \times r_2 - v_1 + \frac{j_r}{m_1} n - {\omega}_1' \times r_1) \cdot n  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{7b} \hspace{5em} = \Big(v_2 - v_1 + j_r({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {\omega}_2' \times r_2 - {\omega}_1' \times r_1\Big) \cdot n \end{equation}

substitute (3a) and (3b) into (7b),

\begin{equation}\tag{8a} = \bigg(v_2 - v_1 + j_r({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {\Big(\omega}_2 + \frac{j_r}{I_2} (r_2 \times n)\Big)\times r_2 - \Big({\omega}_1 - \frac{j_r}{I_1} (r_1 \times n) \Big) \times r_1\bigg) \cdot n  \end{equation}
expanding and simplifying left side,

\begin{equation}\tag{8b} = \Big(v_2 - v_1 + j_r({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {\omega}_2 \times r_2 + j_r{I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2 - {\omega}_1 \times r_1 + j_r{I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1\Big) \cdot n  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{8c} = \bigg(v_2 + {\omega}_2 \times r_2 - (v_1 + {\omega}_1 \times r_1) + j_r\Big(({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2 + {I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1\Big) \bigg) \cdot n  \end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{8d} = \bigg(v_r + j_r\Big(({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2 + {I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1\Big) \bigg) \cdot n  \end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{8e} = v_r \cdot n + \bigg(j_r\Big(({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2 + {I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1\Big) \bigg) \cdot n  \end{equation}

and equating with RHS,

\begin{equation}\tag{9a} j_r \bigg(\Big(({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2 + {I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1\Big) \bigg) \cdot n = -e v_r \cdot n - v_r \cdot n   \end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{9b} j_r  = \frac{-(1 + e)v_r \cdot n}{\Big(({m_2}^{-1} + {m_1}^{-1})n + {I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2 + {I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1\Big) \cdot n}  \end{equation}

which simplifies to,

\begin{equation}\tag{10} j_r  = \frac{-(1 + e)v_r \cdot n}{ {m_1}^{-1} + {m_2}^{-1} + \Big({I_1}^{-1} (r_1 \times n) \times r_1 + {I_2}^{-1} (r_2 \times n) \times r_2\Big) \cdot n}  \end{equation}